# Linq cast to Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string,List<MyClass>>();
```

I am using Linq to obtain a List (from value) via the key

```
List<MyClass> CurrentList = null;
CurrentList = MyDictionary.Where(d => d.Key.Contains(strKey)).Select(x => x.Value).Cast<Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>>();
```

The error I am getting is I can not convert the dictionary to my list.

Have I missed anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you cast to a `Dictionary` if your result must be a `List`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

As `x.Value` is `List<MyClass>`, so you need use `SelectMany`:

```
    List<MyClass> CurrentList = null;
    CurrentList = MyDictionary.Where(d => d.Key.Contains(strKey))
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

`.Select(x => x.Value)`

x.Value is of type `List<MyClass>`, so you cannot cast it as a dictionary. So to fix your code, just use:

`CurrentList = MyDictionary.Where(d => d.Key.Contains(strKey)).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks. Cannot implicitly convert error is now coming up.

Comment: I've changed my code, as I forgot to include `FirstOrDefault()` to retrieve the List (assuming you want just one item returned, if you want more than one, then the other answers given for this question, using SelectMany, should work for you).

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
List<MyClass> CurrentList = null;
CurrentList = MyDictionary.Where(d => d.Key.Contains(strKey)).ToList()
.Where(x => x.Value);
```